# Object Reference for MapPath Field

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

When I try to run this give me exception on class field shown below :

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property 'System.Web.UI.Page.MapPath(string)

Why ?

code behind:

```
public partial class Profile : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(MapPath("~/pic"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(
HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "\\pic"));
```

Comment: Now work. Can you explain me why, and what was the reason of problem ?

Comment: As DiskJunky said, you can use 'at' sign too. TheChampp - it basically return the pic folder inside your website's actual folder. For example, c:\wwwroot\yoursite\pic

Comment: Works without problem with "~" DirectoryInfo dirr = new DirectoryInfo(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/pic"));

Comment: MapPath is a bit slower compare to PhysicalApplicationPath, but it is not much.

Answer (score 1):

try `Server.MapPath()` or `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath()`

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx) documentation :

...the slash (/) at the beginning of the path indicates an absolute virtual path to the site.

So your "~" is erroneous and unneccessary.

Comment: I removed it and again the same problem.

Comment: @TheChampp Is MapPath("/pic") returning a valid result?